# Why does the retry prompt only show once?

Tags: c#, botframework

I've been working with the bot framework for some time now and it always bothered me that the RetryPrompt only shows once.

I've looked through the github source of bot builder and it appears to be that the message actually gets send, but does not get displayed in the Bot Framework Emulator.

Snippet from the MultiTurnPromptBot sample:

```cs
var promptOptions = new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your age."),
                    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("The value entered must be greater than 0 and less than 150."),
                };

                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(NumberPrompt<int>), promptOptions, cancellationToken);
```

I would expect to get the RetryPrompt everytime my message fails the validation.
[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mhJ0.png) the message "The value entered must be greater than 0 and less than 150" gets displayed only once. [But in the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAAhU.png) it actually shows both messages.

My guess is that the emulator get confused because both messages actually have the same id (as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhayJ.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UU1E.png)).

Does anyone know if this is happens in other channels too and/or if this is a bug/feature?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the Emulator. Have filed for the same in the Botframework Emulator repo. You can follow the progress of it in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1684) link.

Comment: @ranusharao wow ... I did not find that issue for some reason. Thank you for linking it! Post it as answer and I will mark it as such so others can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the Emulator. If you look at the log panel in your screenshots, the Activity holding the invalid value message is getting sent in to the Emulator, and you can inspect it normally but it isn't showing up the message in the chat control. Tested it on the latest and previous versions of the Emulator(works fine for the lower version, the bug seems to be in the latest version).

[Attached](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1684) is the link to the bug filed on the BotFramework-Emulator repo.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Fixed: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/pull/2003/files#diff-d7a390bc463ce1da33b33f25899020edL772 and also addressed in dotnet and javascript sdks by clearing out the activity.id on outgoing activities.